# Unexpected element condition while trying to build an ionic app with ant

Tags: java, android, ant, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app which I need to force build using ant.
I am in corporate intranet and so cant use gradle or internet.

So I an forcing to build using ant using the command

```
ionic build android -- --ant.
```

and I get the error

```
BUILD FAILED
Unexpected element condition in ../../build.xml:36.
```

I checked the line and it is a condition setting android sdk directory to android home.

I am using ant 1.5 version and latest ionic.
Sdk is also updated.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem
I was using an old version of ant.

I changed to ant 1.9.0 and it worked without any problem
I guess condition tag came into picture after 1.5